# TVML + autoHighlight + catalog template

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'm currently using the catalogTemplate and the first thing that is highlighted when the app launches is the first category, but I would like to change the focus to the first item in the first category, as clicking on a category does nothing.

```
<catalogTemplate> 
    <banner> 
        <img src="image.png" />
    </banner>
        <background>
        <img src="img.jpg" />   
        </background>

    <list> 
        <section>


            <listItemLockup>
                <img src="ImageThatIsHighlightedByDefault.png"/>
                <decorationLabel />


                <relatedContent>
                    <grid>

                    <header>
                            <description>description</description>
                    </header>

                        <section>
                            <lockup videoURL="VideoIWantToFocus.mp4" autoHighlight="true">
                            <title>title</title>
                            <img src="img.png" />


                            </lockup>
                        </section>
                    </grid>
                 </relatedContent>
            </listItemLockup>
        </section>
```

Comment: Found the answer, the problem was it is not possible to use autohighlight inside the grid element when using the catalog template. From Apple TV Markup Language Reference: The shelf and grid elements can only use the autoHighlight attribute when contained within a productBundleTemplate, productTemplate, or stackTemplate.

Answer (score -1):

Use `autoHighlight="true"` to set the default item you want to present.

In your case, **title** will be first present as it has `autoHighlight="true"` in `lockup`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what am I doing wrong? The above code doesn't work.